# Connect Lenovo T61p with iPhone via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, iphone, thinkpad

Setup: 
- Lenovo T61p (6458-5KG) running Windows7
- iPhone G3S

I am unable to connect my laptop to my iPhone via Bluetooth (I would like to use the iPhone as modem). My system is unable to find the driver for the bluetooth.

Anyone has any input as to where I might find a driver or any other means to get this to work?

I have tried to search the Lenovo website, but without much luck.

I know I can use the USB cable, but it is more convenient to use the wireless option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [GUIDE: iPhone Bluetooth Tethering on Windows Vista](http://modmyi.com/forums/general-iphone-chat/636691-guide-iphone-bluetooth-tethering-windows-vista.html) :

> I found a simple solutions for the
>   dreaded Tethering via Bluetooth on
>   windows.
>
> 1. Setup your iPhone to be able to tether.
> 2. Turn Bluethooth on, on both the iPhone and your computer.
> 3. on your iPhone Goto Settings > General > Network > Internet Tethering and then turn it on.
> 4. on your computer "Network and Sharing Center". Click "Manage Network Connections"
> 5. You should see "Bluetooth Network Connections"
> 6. Right click and goto "View Bluetooth network Devices"
> 7. Add. Then Pair your iPhone with your computer.
> 8. Click Connect.

Other articles that might be useful are:
[iPhone bluetooth and Windows 7](http://forum.eeeuser.com/viewtopic.php?id=74190)
[Activate and Enable iPhone as Internet Tethering Wireless Modem Without Hack or Jailbreak](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/06/28/activate-and-enable-iphone-as-internet-tethering-wireless-modem-without-hack-or-jailbreak/)
[Unable to use Wi-Fi or Bluetooth with iPhone or iPod touch because there's no address listed for the device](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1559)

Comment: Finally got around to actually test this. Works like a charm. Thank you again.